# How to create wildcard views in Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, view

I'm trying to create a view in Postgres using wildcard (*) in the select of a table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.cns_teste1
 AS
 SELECT *
   FROM pkteste;
```

However, the internal mechanism converts this wildcard to the names of the columns in the table definition.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.cns_teste1
 AS
 SELECT pkteste."C1",
    pkteste."V1",
    pkteste."V2"
   FROM pkteste;
```

This does not become a problem when executing the view, however it ends up becoming a problem when updating the database, because if I insert a new column into the table, it is not reflected in the view.

In the case of having just one view, maintenance is easy, but in the case of multiple views, this becomes a problem.

I raised the issue because in **SQL Server**, I can create views with * and whenever I change the table, this is automatically reflected in all views.

Is there any way to maintain views without so much pain? Or even create a view with select using the wildcard (*) to define columns?

Comment: No you can't as the docs state [Create View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html): *CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW is similar, but if a view of the same name already exists, it is replaced. The new query must generate the same columns that were generated by the existing view query (that is, the same column names in the same order and with the same data types), but it may add additional columns to the end of the list.*

Comment: If you are changing the table definitions using `ALTER TABLE`, then you need to recreate all views. DDL queries have side effects.

Comment: MS SQL Server does NOT "automatically" align the views to altered tables, you have to use "WITH SCHEMABINDING" to achieve this. If this is left out then a mssql views acts like a view in Postgres. There is no equivalent to "with schemabinding" in Postgres.

Comment: OK understood!
Thank you all very much for the responses.